# Contest Problem - Darts

Tags: contest-math, markov-chains

Wendy is playing darts with a circular dartboard of radius 20. Whenever she throws a dart, it lands
uniformly at random on the dartboard. At the start of her game, there are 2020 darts placed randomly
on the board. Every turn, she takes the dart farthest from the center, and throws it at the board again.
What is the expected number of darts she has to throw before all the darts are within 10 units of the
center?

Let us call the area within 10 units of the center be I-Inner and the area outside be O-Outer.  There are 2020 darts altogether and the probability that it is in I is $\frac{1}{4}$ and that it is in O is $\frac{3}{4}$. If she takes a dart from O with probability $\frac{3}{4}$ and throws back at the board again, it lands in I with prob $\frac{1}{4}$ and in O with $\frac{3}{4}$. Thus I can think of this as a markov chain and represent this by the following transition matrix.

\begin{pmatrix} &I & O\\
I & 1 & 0\\
O & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4}
\end{pmatrix}

$A= \pmatrix{1&0\cr \frac{1}{4}&\frac{3}{4}}$

$I= 1$

Find the inverse of $(I-A)^{-1} = F$

$(I-A)= 1-\frac{3}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$

$F=4$

From F we can get to find the expected number of turns for the dart to reach the absorbing state is **$4$** for one dart On an average there are $\frac{3}{4}\times 2020 = 1515$ darts in O and by linearity of expectation for 1515 darts, it is $4*1515 = 6060$.

Is this the correct approach of solving the problem in a different way than the solution outlined in the link ( problem number 13 of the Guts round):
[HMMO 2020](https://hmmt-archive.s3.amazonaws.com/tournaments/2020/nov/guts/solutions.pdf).

Could someone verify if this is a valid approach?

Thanks

Comment: As long as there is a dart in $O$ she will take one from $O$.  If it lands in $I$ it will stay there.  You start with a random number of darts in $O$, roughly $1515$, and have $3/4$ chance to decrease it by $1$ each throw.

Comment: The one that is in O shall land in O again thus making it a chain is it not?

Comment: It does land there $3/4$ of the time, so (contrary to my earlier comment) it only decreases $1/4$ of the time.  Yes, it is a chain, but not the one you suggested.

Comment: how would you change my matrix if it is not correct?

Comment: The state I is absorbing.  The matrix should not be symmetric.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I think it is right now?  Let me know. It has been while since I attempted problems like this.  Thanks for correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each individual dart, the expected number of throws until it ends up forever in the inner ring, is 4. However, this includes the initial placement throw! Hence in total, we expect (by additivity) $4\cdot2020$ throws, but have to subtract the $2020$ "preparation“ throws for a final answer of $6060$.

Comment: Is my approach not correct?